# Could not allocate audio samples "Invalid argument"

Tags: sound, desktop-environments, ffmpeg

I trying to open OpenBoard podcast when start recording getting this error and the recorded video does not have audio

```
Invalid path data; path truncated.
Persisting document; path is "/home/sarthak/.local/share/OpenBoard/document/OpenBoard 
 Document 2023-05-09 20-15-50.961/metadata.rdf"
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX 
FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] profile High, level 6.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] 264 - core 164 r3095 baee400 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - 
Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 
deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 
me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 
chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 
interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=10 
keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=20.0 
qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
```

**Could not allocate audio samples "Invalid argument"**

```
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] frame I:1     Avg QP: 0.00  size:   151
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] frame P:1     Avg QP: 0.00  size:    30
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  
0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:100.0%
 [libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] 8x8 transform intra:0.0%
 [libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 0.0% 0.0%       
  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] i16 v,h,dc,p: 97%  0%  3%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5637cd236840] kb/s:0.34
[aac @ 0x5637cd1deec0] Qavg: nan
Persisting document; path is "/home/sarthak/.local/share/OpenBoard/document/OpenBoard 
Document 2023-05-09 20-15-50.961/metadata.rdf"
```